# Replace double slashes with single one, except for the first match in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Let's say we have an URL like:

```
https://mywebsite.com//hello/world//foo/bar
```

So I need a way in Ruby (regular expression) to make the URL look like this:

```
https://mywebsite.com/hello/world/foo/bar
```

(It could also be `http` or simply with `//`).

I have tried forging such a regex, but I don't think it matches all double slashes, but works only for one match:

```
(?<=https:\/\/)(.+)(\/\/)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use double look-behind assertions here:

```
(?<!http:)(?<!https:)//
```

Example:

```
s = 'https://mywebsite.com//hello/world//foo/bar'
s.gsub(Regexp.new('(?<!http:)(?<!https:)//'), '/')
# => "https://mywebsite.com/hello/world/foo/bar"
```

Comment: How about when an URL starts with `//` instead of `http://` or `https://`? I know I didn't mention this in the first post, but I would appreciate help on this one too.

Comment: Well, if it's at the beginning of the string, I suppose `(?<!^)(?<!http:)(?<!https:)//`

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `URI` for that, it's as simple as

```
require 'uri'

u = URI.parse('https://mywebsite.com//hello/world//foo/bar')
u.path.gsub!('//', '/')
u.to_s #=> "https://mywebsite.com/hello/world/foo/bar"
```

This way you can be sure to modify only the path of the url, nothing else.

More info on `URI` can be found [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/URI)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern that is not anchored to the substring `https://`:

```
\/(?=\/)(?<!https:\/)
```

or a version that do not depend of the scheme:

```
\/(?=\/)(?<!:\/)
```

And use an empty string as replacement.

[demo](http://rubular.com/r/ot0LmZyBag)

Note: if you want to handle URIs like `file:///directory/...` you can add an alternation in the negative lookbehind:

```
\/(?=\/)(?<!:\/|:\/\/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
require 'uri'
url = "https://mywebsite.com//hello/world//foo/bar"
components = URI.split(url).compact
components.last.gsub!("//","/")
components.first.to_s + "://" + components[1..-1].join
# => "https://mywebsite.com/hello/world/foo/bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

If colon is a device delimiter
find `(?<!:)/+`
replace `/`

Input:

```
https://mywebsite.com//hello/world//foo/bar
https:///mywebsite.com////hello/world//foo/bar
///////////mywebsite.com//hello/world//foo/bar
/mywebsite.com/hello/world/foo/bar
```

Output:

```
https://mywebsite.com/hello/world/foo/bar
https://mywebsite.com/hello/world/foo/bar
/mywebsite.com/hello/world/foo/bar
/mywebsite.com/hello/world/foo/bar
```

Answer (score -1):

What about escaping the first double slash into something else, doing a simple `gsub`, and then unescaping? Assuming that your string never includes `"ESCAPE"` (if it does, you can choose something else):

```
"https://mywebsite.com//hello/world//foo/bar"
.sub("//", "ESCAPE")
.gsub("//", "/")
.sub("ESCAPE", "//")
```